# Running iOS app in background

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I want to post the user's current latitude and longitude to the server periodically.Posting is happening fine when the application is running the foreground.But is there any way to do  it if the application is running in the background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this's just what you're searching for?

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-multitasking-background-location/

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know you should not call any time consuming functions in applicationDidEnterBackground since the app will get suspended after a short amount of time.

From Apple's IOS Programming Guide

> Most applications that enter the background state are moved to the
>   suspended state shortly thereafter. While in this state, the
>   application does not execute any code and may be removed from memory
>   at any time. Applications that provide specific services to the user
>   can request background execution time in order to provide those
>   services.

Answer (score 0):

AR Body detection

if the user does the correct move then a message shows to say that the move was correct if not then a message is sent to say that you didn't complete the move